# Conditionally send results to specific emails

Tags: webforms

Hello Looking for some advice on how to deal with sending conditional emails. I did some research and it can be done in Drupal 7 with Rules but since I'm new to Drupal 8 I haven't been able to figure it out.

Here is my scenario

I have a select list called - TOPICS

In that select list I select SPONSORSHIP

When I click submit result goes to a specific email based on that selection

OR if I select a different topic say ADVERTISING it goes to a different email based on that selection.

Thank You in advance for any help!

Comment: I figured it out but leaving the post for those find it. Fix is found under documentation https://www.drupal.org/node/273806

Comment: The author of the webform module says that routing emails via a drop-down list is suported. But as more information is unavailable, we might want to write a hook in a module, e.t. get our hands dirty and implement hook_form_alter.
Update: We don't need a module, it works this way: